# Длина таблицы MySQL(кол-во ячеек)

Tags: jdbc, mysql

Требуется создать таблицу в базе.

**Ячейки**
 1. *Номер
 2. Дата
 3. Клиент
 4. Контакт
 5. Толщина
 6. Размеры(x,y,z)
 7. Цвет
 8. Трафарет (+/-)
 9. Сложность
 10. Склейка
 11. Стоимость*

Получается очень длинная таблица. Реализую всё через JDBC и вывод будет через апплет. Будет ли корректно создавать такую большую таблицу? 
Возможно ли как-то разделить таблицу? Но при печати на лист(выводе в апплет), в ней должны быть все ячейки.

зы Изучаю на этом проекте java. Можно ли другим способом реализовать такую таблицу?
XML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Разумеется, Вашу структуру надо нормализовать. Всего лишь надо поля `3. Клиент 4. Контакт` заменить на поле "ИД_Контакта", которое бы ссылалось на запись в таблице "Контакт" с полями "ИД, Клиент, Контакт". Да, Вы экономите всего одно поле, но структура становится ближе к нормальной форме (да и просто логичнее) - заодно изучите соотношение "один-ко-многим" и операцию `JOIN` :)

Если же записей будет немного, смысла делать поддержку полноценной СУБД нет. Можно сделать на встраиваемой СУБД, например, sqlite3 (насколько помню, поддержка ее в jdbc есть), а можно, действительно, на  XML-файлах, хоть такое решение мне лично не по душе.

Думать о количестве полей просто как о количестве полей - бессмысленно. В моей практике встречалась таблица, в которой было около сотни полей - и улучшить это было малореально.

Вообще, рекомендую почитать какую-нибудь теорию по СУБД, минимально привязанную к конкретной реализации (никаких "Освой Oracle за 15 минут") - например:

1. Дейт К. Дж. Введение в системы баз данных.
2. Гарсиа-Молина Г., Ульман Дж., Уидом Дж. Системы баз данных. Полный курс.

Это только то, что вспомнил сходу.

Успехов!

Comment: иес) сенк)

Comment: Вы знаете) Я разочаровался)  Скачал SqLite Admin и понял, что моё приложение не нужно) В SqLite admin реализовано то, что надо было мне реализовать(

Comment: В принципе, ту задачу можно было и при помощи LibreOffice Calc или любой другой электронной таблицы решить - но это «неспортивно» :-) Сделайте с web-интерфейсом, получите ценный опыт - лишним не будет! 

Успехов!

Comment: Извините, веб-интерфейс - это когда через браузер?:) я просто делал как отдельный апплет...А если реализовывать через сервлеты - то это уже напряжно будет с точки зрения использования) Хотя...Опять же ценный опыт, поработаю с jsp...И, там вроде, тема Spring'a задевается...
Я правильно рассуждал?

Answer (score 0):

Ну безусловно можно на несколько разделить такую таблицу и использовать внешние ключи.
Например в отдельную таблицу занести изделия.

Comment: Ой.. а я что-то подумал про другое :) Должно быть вопрос сформулирован как-то нечётко..

Comment: Нет, вы всё правильно подумали. Просто Ваш совет через ключи, я не совсем понял. Что такое ключи - знаю. А как правильно поделить? Между строками таблицы ничего общего не будет. Клиенты не повторяются, Размеры заказов - тоже, остальное - вообще чисто технические вопросы....О! А если их отдельно выносить...просто не могу понять, как зависимости расставить(

Answer (score 0):

Вы имеете в виду что таблица будет длинная? Ну так сделайте какой-нибудь Lazy-load.. свинговую таблицу легко запилить под это и грузите небольшиме порциями on-demand. Вот только через JDBC через весь интернет не надо это делать... не очень красиво получится..

Comment: Приложение будет стоять на локальном компьютере и на нём же использоваться, это вроде, Стэнд элон называется)
Ладно. Технические подробности уточнять не буду, на это есть гугл. А вот с реализацией - получается реализую в одну таблицу(не как Vlad Lisovsky предложил. 

А почему вы говорите, что через JDBC, через весь интернет - не красиво? Ни разу просто не сталкивался с этим, самоучка.

Comment: Ну просто вообще небезопасно, чтобы в интернет торчала БД. Лучше сделать на сервере какой-нибудь веб-сервис, чтобы через него получать данные и тем самым ограничить потенциальный доступ и снизить риски. Кроме того, количество подключений к базе и количество сессий БД ограничены сильнее, чем количество HTTP-соединений.

Comment: А что на эту тему почитать можно? Безопасность? Реализация веб-сервисов? (не представляю пока, что такое веб-сервис, как оно реализовано? Схема получается - 
Пользователь -> Веб сайт -> приложение на сервере -> БД  (и обратно)
Так это получается как сервлет?